# What is $\left[\frac{1}{2}(p-1)\right]! \;(\text{mod } p)$ for $p = 4k+1$?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Theorem #114 in Hardy and Wright says if $p = 4k+3$ then

$$ \left[\frac{1}{2}(p-1)\right]!  \equiv (-1)^\nu \mod p$$

where $\nu = \# \{ \text{non residues mod } p\text{ less than }p/2\}$.

- Is there corresponding result for $p = 4k+1$?

In that case, Hardy just says the factorial is one $\pm \sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ but he doesn't say which one.  When is this value greater than or less than $\frac{p}{2}$ ?

- How do we estimate the number $\nu$ of quadratic residues mod p?

Maybe this paper of [Burgess](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/res/burgess.pdf) on the distribution of quadratic residues will help.

Comment: How is the number of quadratic residues related? Don't you just care about $-1$?

Comment: @nayrb the original theorem just asks about whether $\nu$ is even or odd.  that might be good enough.

Comment: I missed that. The original statement is more curious then I thought at first glance. It's obvious to me it's either $1$ or $-1$ but why based on number of quadratic residues?

Comment: @nayrb A similar statement is [Gauss' Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(number_theory)) in Number Theory which counts the number of residues of $\{ a, 2a, \dots, \tfrac{p-1}{2} a\}$ less than $p/2$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ there are exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic residues, and if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, $-1$ is a quadratic residue, hence the quadratic residues are symmetrically distributed around $\frac{p}{2}$, so the number of quadratic residues less than $\frac{p}{2}$ is just $\frac{p-1}{4}$.

Comment: whoops :-) my 2nd question would be nontrivial if I said "less than $\frac{p}{4}$"

Comment: @johnmangual: you're still in time to modify your question as well as I am still in time to delete my very trivial answer :)