# Given a prime number $p>2$, calculate $\left(\frac{p-1}{2} \right)! \mod p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Since $(p-1)!\mod p = -1$ and $$(p-1)!\mod p \\
= \prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}k(p-k) \mod p\\
= (-1)^\frac{p-1}{2} \prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}k^2 \mod p\\
= (-1)^\frac{p-1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2 \mod p$$

we have $$(-1)^\frac{p-1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2 \mod p = -1$$

which further induces $$\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2 \mod p=\begin{cases}1, \text{   if }\frac{p-1}{2}\text{ is odd}\\
p-1, \text{   otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

If $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is odd then $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\mod p$ can be $1$ or $p-1$. If it is even, there are also two possible values.

My problem is

1. how to solve $x^2\mod p = p-1$
2. determine correct value of $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!$

Comment: Does the task exclude $p=2$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234680/what-is-left-frac12p-1-right-textmod-p-for-p-4k1?

Comment: Mhm $(p-1)! = -1$ mod $p$, not $1$